# Show 3G icons like Android

Tags: 14.04

It is possible add "G" "E" "3G" "H+" icons over taskbar, like android, when connected using a USB HSPA+ modem? My signal type changes very often in my city, and i'd like to see signal type besides signal strenght at tasbar.

[image]

Comment: Run this command in terminal and keep the network occupied, so 3G won't change to EDGE. `ping www.google.com -s 1`